# split data in a single column into multiple columns in oracle

Tags: oracle, join, pivot, decode

my_table :

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| item_1 | AB |
| item_2 | 2 |
| item_3 | B1 |
| item_1 | CD |
| item_1 | EF |
| item_2 | 3 |
| item_3 | B2 |
| item_4 | ZZ |

required output:

| item_1 | item_2 | item_3 | item_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AB | 2 | B1 | ZZ |
| CD | 3 | B2 | NULL |
| EF | NULL | NULL | NULL |

SQL query :

```
with item_1 as (select value from my_table where name  = 'item_1'),
item_2 as (select value from my_table where name  = 'item_2'),
item_3 as (select value from my_table where name  = 'item_3'),
item_4 as (select value from my_table where name  = 'item_4')
select item_1.value, item_2.value,item_3.value, item_4.value from item_1 cross join item_2 cross join item_3 cross join item_4;
```

If I am using pivot along with MAX aggregate function, the query will display only max values of the corresponding items instead of displaying all the values.

Is there any way to split a single column into multiple columns(using where condition as mentioned in the above query) without cross join.

Comment: How do you know which values go together - that '3' goes with 'CD' and not 'EF', for example; and why isn't 'B2' in the output? Is there another column you haven't shown that links things (which you could use to group-by for the pivot)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER` and then `PIVOT`:

```sql
SELECT item_1,
       item_2,
       item_3,
       item_4
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY ROWNUM) AS rn
  FROM   table_name t
)
PIVOT (
  MAX(value) FOR name IN (
    'item_1' AS item_1,
    'item_2' AS item_2,
    'item_3' AS item_3,
    'item_4' AS item_4
  )
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (Name, Value) AS
SELECT 'item_1', 'AB' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'item_2', '2'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'item_3', 'B1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'item_1', 'CD' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'item_1', 'EF' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'item_2', '3'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'item_3', 'B2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'item_4', 'ZZ' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | ITEM_1 | ITEM_2 | ITEM_3 | ITEM_4 |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | AB | 2 | B1 | ZZ |
> | CD | 3 | B2 | *null* |
> | EF | *null* | *null* | *null* |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=b491be68f5d6a70e8963448b2db62a42)*

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

`DF` column is calculated by `row_number` analytic function which partitions by each name (and sorts by value). It is ignored from the final column list, but its role is *crucial* in the `GROUP BY` clause.

```
SQL> with test (name, value) as
  2    (select 'item_1', 'AB' from dual union all
  3     select 'item_2', '2'  from dual union all
  4     select 'item_3', 'B1' from dual union all
  5     select 'item_1', 'CD' from dual union all
  6     select 'item_1', 'EF' from dual union all
  7     select 'item_2', '3'  from dual union all
  8     select 'item_3', 'B2' from dual union all
  9     select 'item_4', 'ZZ' from dual
 10    ),
```

---

```
 11  temp as
 12    (select name, value,
 13       row_number() over (partition by name order by value) df
 14     from test
 15    )
 16  select
 17    max(case when name = 'item_1' then value end) item_1,
 18    max(case when name = 'item_2' then value end) item_2,
 19    max(case when name = 'item_3' then value end) item_3,
 20    max(case when name = 'item_4' then value end) item_4
 21  from temp
 22  group by df;

ITEM_1 ITEM_2 ITEM_3 ITEM_4
------ ------ ------ ------
AB     2      B1     ZZ
CD     3      B2
EF

SQL>
```